# How to change the page using Navigator.push so that the body and header animation is different, while the footer remains unchanged

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to go to the next page using **Navigator.push** and at the same time change only the body on the page. I only got this when, for example, I wrap the index of page 2 in **materialApp**. But when I decided to make the animation (it smoothly pushes the old page to the left and pushes the new page to the right), it turned out that she pushed the old page, but behind it was exactly the same motionless page, which was later blocked by the new one.

I understood this in such a way that the first deleted page was an index 2 page, which is wrapped in **MaterialApp**, and behind it is exactly the same fixed **MaterialApp** for the entire application. At the moment, I have no idea how to remove a fixed page. I gave a picture of how I am currently navigating in the application, it may not be perfect, but I do not know better, any help would be appreciated.

In many applications, I see such an animation that the header fades out smoothly and at the same time a new one appears. And the body at this moment is replaced with the old page with a smooth movement, I really like it and I want to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use nested Navigator inside your scaffold.

Page index 1,2 and 3 will be inside the root Navigator under material app. Page 2 will contain another Navigator to fit your purpose.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> outgoingKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Sample',
          home: Scaffold(
            body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Page1(), 
          Page2(navigatorKey: outgoingKey,),
          Page3(),
        ],
        pageSnapping: false,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      ),
            bottomNavigationBar: /*SomeBottomNavigationBar()*/,
          ),
        );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Page2({Key key, this.navigatorKey}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Navigator(
            key: navigatorKey, // you need to use this to pop i.e. navigatorKey.currentState.pop()
            initialRoute: 'initialPageIndex2',
             onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder _builder;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case 'nextPageForPageIndex2':
             _builder = (context) => /*NextPageForPageIndex2()*/;
             break;
          case 'initialPageIndex2':
          default:
            _builder = (context) => /*InitialPageIndex2()*/;
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: _builder);
      },
      transitionDelegate: DefaultTransitionDelegate(),
    );
            )
      ],)
    );
  }
}


class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('Page1'),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('Page3'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, your answer helped me, now the body is gradually changing to a new one. But now I have a problem with the header, the fact is that it also needs to be changed depending on the page. If header and body are not connected to each other, then everything is fine, but I use VievModelBuilder on the page inside which Scuffold body and appBar are closely connected. Do you know how to carefully and correctly disconnect them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the PageView please check the code below, hope it will help you :

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Page1(),
          Page2()
        ],
        pageSnapping: false,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child:Text("Page 1")),
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child:Text("Page 2")),
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can explore  here https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-pageview-widget-e0f6c8092636

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, yes, I already thought about it, but there is one problem. The fact is that this page can be very long (when you click on the converted line, it should open the same way, only with different data, etc. ad infinitum). You can add a new widget to the <Widget> list and use the controller to switch the widget, and when the user returns, remove the last widget and also update the icon in the header, you will need a “go back” icon. This will be a real hemorrhoids, and a crutch, I believe, will be implemented in this project, so I searched with Navigator.Push.

Comment: I changed the question a little, I think now it more clearly expresses my thoughts. If you have ideas how to implement this, please write